# Convert PHP Array to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I know there is a bunch of another topics related to converting array php to json results, but what I need is a little bit specific, I appreciate if someone else could help to get the expected result.

I have tried to generated the following JSON result using some arrays or 2 dimension arrays but it does not work properly.

Could someone else help me to get this result as JSON value as below?

```
{
 "header": {
  "key": {
   "name": "JSAGUINA",
   "workstationName": "PRODUCTION"
  }
 },
 "jobs": [{
  "jobDefinition": {
   "header": {
    "jobDefinitionKey": {
     "name": "JOBAGUINA",
     "workstationName": "PRODUCTION"
    }
   }
  },
  "header": {
   "key": {
    "name": "JOBAGUINA",
    "jobStreamKey": {
     "name": "JSAGUINA",
     "workstationName": "PRODUCTION"
    }
   }
  }
 }, {
  "jobDefinition": {
   "header": {
    "jobDefinitionKey": {
     "name": "JOBAGUINA_1",
     "workstationName": "PRODUCTION"
    }
   }
  },
  "header": {
   "key": {
    "name": "JOBAGUINA_1",
    "jobStreamKey": {
     "name": "JSAGUINA",
     "workstationName": "PRODUCTION"
    }
   }
  },
  "internalDependencies": [{
   "jobKey": {
    "name": "JOBAGUINA",
    "jobStreamKey": {
     "name": "JSAGUINA",
     "workstationName": "PRODUCTION"
    }
   }
  }]
 }]
}
```

Comment: can you add up a code, to show where you stopped so we can help in figuring which is the best and where your logical errors are

Comment: I'm not seeing anything overly unique with your notation, everything is an object unless its an array of objects (where the square bracket notation starts)

Comment: echo json_encode($array); isn't this working?

Comment: please share the php array code also.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell where your error is without seeing the content of the PHP array.

Use `echo json_encode($arr);` to get this array. If you get as a return try to convert the values to utf-8 before using json_encode (helped me in most cases).

For further debugging you should use `json_last_error`

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode() to convert array to json:

```
echo json_encode($yourarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I am able to generate the JSON correctly but its still missing one point as you guys can see below, its missing the last 2 elements "tasksString" and "recoveryOption" properly:

See last two elements below are not in the correct position of the array. They should be after the "},".

**expected:**

```
'{
                                 "header": {
                                    "jobDefinitionKey": {
                                        "name": "'. $jobname .'",
                                        "workstationName": "' . $wks . '"
                                    },
                                    "description": "' . $descrip . '",
                                    "taskType": "' . $tasktype . '",
                                    "isCommand": "'. $command .'",
                                    "userLogin": "' . $userlogin . '"
                                    },
                                    "taskString": "' . $taskcmd . '",
                                    "recoveryOption": "STOP"
                                }';
```

**Code:**

```
$object->header = array (
    'jobDefinitionKey' => array (
            'name' => $jobname,
            'workstationName' => $wks 
    ),
    'description' => $descrip,
    'taskType' => $tasktype,
    'isCommand' => $command,
    'userLogin' => $userlogin,

            'taskString' => $taskcmd,
            'recoveryOption' => 'STOP'
    ) ;
```

**my JSON result:**

```
{
"header": {
    "jobDefinitionKey": {
        "name": null,
        "workstationName": null
    },
    "description": null,
    "taskType": null,
    "isCommand": null,
    "userLogin": null,
    "taskString": null,
    "recoveryOption": "STOP"
}
```

}

Comment: See last two elements below are not in the correct position of the array...

        "taskString": null,
    "recoveryOption": "STOP"